# Pascal sum calculator

Tags: sum, pascal

What is the sum of this one (lets says that the value of x is 2)

[image]

I have used pascal to solve this and this is

```
Program Somme ;
var
  n,factoriel,denominateur : longint ;
  Numerateur,x,x_sqr,somme_total:real;
begin
  writeln('Bienvenue dans le programme : "La somme numerique".');
  writeln(' ');
  write('Veuillez saisir la valeur numerique de x puis appuyez sur "entre" : ');
  read(x);
  somme_total:=0;
  x_sqr:= 1;
  factoriel:=1;
  for n:= 1 to 10 do
  begin
    factoriel:= factoriel*n;
    x_sqr:=x*x_sqr;
    Numerateur:= n+x_sqr;
    denominateur:=(2*factoriel)+1;
    somme_total:=somme_total + (Numerateur/denominateur);
  end;
  writeln('La somme total est : ',somme_total )
end.
```

here is my teacher answer (I think that it's wrong)

```
program Somme;
uses wincrt;
var n : integer;
 F,P,S,x,somme : real;
Begin
  writeln ('Entrez la valeur de x ');
  readln(x);

  writeln ('===== Calcule de la Somme ====== ');
  writeln;
  F := 1;
  P := 1;
  S := 0;
  for n := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    F := F* n;
    P := P *x;
    S:= (n+P) / (2*F)+1;
    writeln ('Resultat de l étiration ', n, ' est égale: ', S:2:2);

    somme :=somme +S;
  end;
  writeln;
  writeln ('La somme S est égale: ', S:2:2);
  writeln;
end.
```

so which one is correct?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong/different? do you get different numbers? At a quick glance they look the same.

Comment: Your is correct. Have you identified the error or errors in the code you have marked as your teachers answer?

Comment: Your teacher's version contains a small but obvious error. Can you spot it?

Comment: A/B+1 = 1+A/B <> A/(B+1)

Comment: hey, thanks for the answers, i have got the errors and my solution was right!